# MySQL for locally saved database , are there any alternatives

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have been trying to save some data into txt files, but now I have decided to use a database to store these values. But I can't seem to find how can this be achieved, I've read through some tutorials but they all seem to be for online app building.

Are there any modules that can be used to create MySQL database on my hard disk , are there any alternatives ?

Is it necessary to make a server even if i'm using the database on the same computer for some local stuff ?

Comment: You may use mysqldump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a local database, you can use the builtin sqlite3-database.